# GLTF load warning--- Timer GLTF loader already exists

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, 8thwall-web

I am using A-Frame javascript 8th wall libarary and tap place component to place a model. When I tap on the screen iam getting the above warning and after 2 minutes or so I can see the model on the screen. I am not using any gltfloaders it is just plain  html5, javascript with aframe tap-place component.

Is this something normal or am I doing wrong in my coding? Thanks in advance for helping!

My git link - https://github.com/NishithaSurapudi/tap_place

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the warning is coming from three.js which the 8thwall lib depends on. Try updating to the latest version of aframe, but if you can't fix it, its a minor warning so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `console.time` is called multiple times with the same label. If you load a single model with GLTFLoader, everything should work fine. The warning shows when you start loading multiple models.